# Bad Request Error - Setting up Heroku to receive Incoming Email using SendGrid and Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I'm having trouble setting up SendGrid with rails 6 in Heroku. I use Mailbox in rails and set SendGrid in ingress. As mention in Rails documentation, this URL should be added in SendGrid `https://actionmailbox:PASSWORD@example.com/rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails`, but when I try to add this link SendGrid is responding a "Bad Request" message.

According to SendGrid Documentation https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook/ I should first set the MX Record, but I can't find MX Recond in Heroku.

What could be the problem with this one? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! You just need to delete the existing Host & URL in SendGrid.

For MX Record, you can do it in your DNS Host, not in Heroku.

Thanks!